# How can I get variable with the text from this html?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to get the text type ('14') as a variable from this html

```
<div class="hale_sup"></div>
  <button class="hale" aria-disabled="true" type="button" disabled="" aria-label="Previous page"></button>
  <div class="hale_2"><input tabindex="0" type="text" size="2" aria-label="Current page" value="1"></div>
  'of'
  '14'
```

I tried to get the text ('14')

```
text = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div [@class='hale_sup']/text()[1]")
```

I get this error: The result of the xpath expression is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

I have also tried:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div [@class='hale_sup']").text().
```

In order to obtain both text but appears

```
'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: would you pls post the complete dom/html? your `of` and `14` are not part of  `class="hale_sup"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text is an attribute, not a function, you can try:

```
print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div [@class='hale_sup']/..").text)
```

Comment: It appears as empty

Comment: Yes, actually there should be a parent element that actually contains that text. The text you want does not belong to element `//div [@class='hale_sup']` belong to his parent, can you edit your question adding the parent of that element?

Comment: Or even you could try with the answer, I edited it, maybe it should be enough